# How to set initial value as Select in the dropdown of asp.net page that is databound with sql statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am binding a dropdown for location with a select statment

```
Select location_id, location_name,businessid from inventory.tbl_location order by location_name
```

I want to put the first element as 'Select location'. Right now I am getting all locations. How to set initial value as ***Select*** in the dropdown of asp.net page  that is databound with sql statement?

```
In the aspx page :

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAllLocations" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBusinessLocations"
                            DataTextField="Location_Name" DataValueField="Location_ID" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceBusinessLocations" runat="server" ConnectionString="<xxxxxx>"
            ProviderName="<%$ zzzzz %>" SelectCommand="Select location_id, location_name,businessid from inventory.tbl_location order by location_name" FilterExpression="businessid in ({0})">
            <FilterParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="BUID" SessionField="BusinessUnitIDs" />
            </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I added the code as suggested in the page_load event, here is another problem, everytime it is adding **select location** to  the list items

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack() Then
            lblError.Text = ""
            ddlAllLocations.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select location"))
        End If


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAllLocations" runat="server"
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBusinessLocations"
       DataTextField="Location_Name" 
       DataValueField="Location_ID" 
       AutoPostBack="True"
       AppendDataBoundItems="True">
   <asp:ListItem value="" selected="True">
      Select
   </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Don't forget the `AppendDataBoundItems` attribute. Be careful using this in an update panel: each update will re-append all the items and you'll end up with duplicates. In that case, you might be able to fix it by disabling ViewState for the control.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you do the databinding but I hope you're doing it in code-behind...

In that case it's pretty straighforward:

```
mydroplist.DataSource = someSource;
mydroplist.DataBind();
mydroplist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select location"));
```

**edit based on your edit:**
it's not a good idea to have SQL in your UI.. That's a very bad design. Do some research on proper programming architectures, how to separate layers etc. Then you will do the databinding in code-behind and my sample will help you.

If you insist on using your way of doing things, you can simply wire up the event when the dropdownlist is databound and add this piece of code (except the binding part of course)

Comment: can i do something like this select distinct [acc-business-id] as businessid, [acc-business-area] as businessarea from tbl_Business_Units  
union
(select null as BusinessID, '-Select-' as BusinessArea)   thisishow it is done for another field. I want to do similar to this in sp

Comment: @PeterJennings, you know that you're violating multiple programming principles at once, right? Tight-coupling is always a bad thing to do in programming and you're taking it even one step further... I know you probably don't care, but I can't suggest you a solution like that.

Comment: In the page_load event..I have written  ddlAllLocations.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select location"))           nothing is happening...not able to see "select location' in the dropdownlist

Comment: @walther I agree with you on multi-layer project; it is a must for a project with multiple pages. If Peter's project has only a couple of page, it'll be over kill for him.

Comment: @PeterJennings, I didn't say you should put it in Page_Load, but in `DataBound` after you subscribe for the corresponding event.....

Comment: @Win, I can't agree with you on this.. Even if that was a single page website, what's the point of learning the worst possible way of doing it?